# Using %userprofile% to navigate to current user when running CMD as admin

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a .bat that needs to run as admin although this creates problems with parts of the .bat when `%userprofile%` is used it will navigate to system32 rather than the userprofile that the .bat is run on.

I don't have any need to navigate to system32 with the .bat so if there was a way to correct this from the start of the .bat so following commands could be run as the currently logged in user.

Comment: Try `help cd` and `help pushd`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

```
cd /d "%userprofile%"
```

or

```
pushd "%userprofile%"
```

Comment: Am I missing something as this I get a syntax error with `pushd /d "%userprofile%"` and my `REN` command still points to system32
`REN "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\something" "something1"`

Comment: Were you to enter `help pushd` at the prompt as suggested in the comment below your question, you'd have noted that there was a typo in the answer above, now fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Compo, I should have caught that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue seems to be how the .bat is being used (through LogMeIn) for some reason it was going to system32 even using the `pushd /d "%userprofile%"` command I found a workaround that works with logmein is the following

```
pushd "%~dp0"
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
```

Comment: Since you never posted an MCVE, none of us had any idea there was another script involved here.